# Get variables in URL

Tags: php, url, query-string

i have searched and found this
http://html.net/tutorials/php/lesson10.php

but, my question is i want to pass a couple of parameters BUT i need the same variable name .. not sure if that made sense so ex

index.php?Model=XYZ&page=1,2,34

so basically, i will want the page to pop up and goto a directory XYZ and pull the images regarding 1, 2 and 34. so most likely 1.jpg 2.jpg and 34.jpg

is that possible? Not sure what keyword to search for.

Comment: There are other ways to do this, but what you have should also work. What's the problem?

Comment: Use PHP to generate dynamic html and layout the three images with `<img>` tags; or use JavaScript to do it?

Answer (score 1):

Use array syntax for your parameter names:

```
index.php?Model=XYZ&page[]=1&page[]=2&page[]=34
```

Then in your code:

```
$page = $_GET['page'];
echo $page[0]; // prints 1

var_dump($page);
array(3) {
  [0]=>
  int(1)
  [1]=>
  int(2)
  [2]=>
  int(34)
}
```

Answer (score 1):

If you call following Url

```
index.php?Model=XYZ&page=1,2,34
```

You can do it with following PHP

```
$pages = isset ($_GET['pages']) ? explode(',', $_GET['pages']) : [];
print_r($pages);

foreach ($pages as $page) {
    //If no Number, ignore
    if (!is_numeric($page)) {
        continue;
    }

    //Cast to Integer
    $page = (int)$page;

    //Work with $page
    echo $page;
}
```

Also hear about `UrlRewriting` for IIS or `ModRewrite` for Apache